# Regex conditional: give the user exactly two options

Tags: regex, opencms

The user has to type in his/her customer number in a browser form. The backend is built with java-based OpenCMS.

The customer number consists of 8 alphanumerical, a slash then another 3 chars (i.e., 12 chars in total). However, sometimes users forget the slash. If the latter is the case, we just have 11 alphanumerical chars.

How to give the user the option to either write the customer number either with or without slash?

Valid inputs are:

> a1234567/123
>   01234567/321
>
> 01234567890
>   a0123456789

Currently, I just managed to restrict regex to 12 alpha-numerical chars.

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]{12}$
```

We have to start with the ^-sign and end with the $-sign.

Comment: Could you please share your regular expression? And the language/regex flavor since we are talking about a slash.

Comment: Can you give a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) about what you want to do? or the code that you have tried so far?

Comment: @stribizhev: Sorry, I'm new to regex. Is this better? I hate downvotes ;) anyhow, olexd gave the working answer.

Comment: @Kasra jan: Thx for the excellent link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matching regular expression:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}\/?[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}$
```

first exact `8 alphanumeric chars`, then optional `slash` and exact `3 alphanumeric chars`

Comment: It will be working if `^` and `$` are added. Otherwise, it will match `$#$@#abcdfgas/123^&&^*&(`.